# Hibernate exception SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

getting this exception when running a named query

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
.....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
.....
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 40, Sql = select s1 from SystemParameterValueImpl as s1 join s1.systemParameter as p1 
                where p1.id = :1  and s1.effectiveGasDay = 
                    (select max(s2.effectiveGasDay ) 
                    from SystemParameterValueImpl s2 join s2.systemParameter as p2 
                    where p1.id = p2.id and s2.effectiveGasDay <= :2 ) 
                order by p1.id, 
OriginalSql = select s1 from SystemParameterValueImpl as s1 join s1.systemParameter as p1 
                where p1.id = ? and s1.effectiveGasDay = 
                    (select max(s2.effectiveGasDay ) 
                    from SystemParameterValueImpl s2 join s2.systemParameter as p2 
                    where p1.id = p2.id and s2.effectiveGasDay <= ?) 
                order by p1.id, Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

this is the named query in my hbm file

```
    <sql-query  name="findSystemParameterValueApplicableOnDate">
        <return class="com.amor.hcplus.application.systemparameter.domain.SystemParameterValueImpl" />
            <![CDATA[
                select s1 from SystemParameterValueImpl as s1 join s1.systemParameter as p1 where p1.id = :parameterName and s1.effectiveGasDay = (select max(s2.effectiveGasDay ) from SystemParameterValueImpl s2 join s2.systemParameter as p2 where p1.id = p2.id and s2.effectiveGasDay <= :date) order by p1.id
            ]]>
    </sql-query>
```

and here is where i call the namedQuery

```
        SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) getSession().getNamedQuery("findSystemParameterValueApplicableOnDate")
                .setParameter("parameterName", parameterName)
                .setParameter("date", date);
        
        List list = query.list();
```

Comment: The problem is with your SQL query and has nothing to do with Hibernate. `join` is for joining two database tables. You seem to be trying to join a database table with a column in that table. Also, is `s1` a column in database table `SystemParameterValueImpl`? If not then maybe you mean `select s1.*`? I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the structure of the database tables involved in your query, i.e. the column names and their data types. It may also help if you post some sample data as well as your expected result of your database query based on that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'AS' keyword to define the table alias

This is an example of how to write a join:

```
SELECT gn.*
FROM GENERAL_NOTIFICATIONS gn
JOIN NOTIFICATION_ROLE nr ON (cign.ID = cinr.NOTIFICATION_ID)
```

Comment: I don't see the [database] table names nor columns in the SQL in the original question. Maybe you made a mistake and answered a different question to the one you intended to answer?